# Ensuring the absence of an __init__ function in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, initialization, python-import

I'm writing a plugin-based application. Part of the specification for a plugin is that a plugin **must not** implement the `__init__` method, as any initialization needs to be handled by the plugin manager, not the plugin itself. (A plugin writer would define their startup code in another method, called by the plugin manager after some checks are satisfied.)

To enforce this style, the plugin manager should fail, throw an exception, or perform some other discouraging action if `__init__` is being used.

I thought I could just check to see if `__init__` is defined:

```py
# minimaltest.py
__meta__ = "Minmimal metadata"
```

```py
# main.py
import minimaltest
hasattr(minimaltest, '__meta__')  # => True
hasattr(minimaltest, '__somethingimadeup__')  # => False
hasattr(minimaltest, '__init__')  # => True?!
```

Problem: That `hasattr` call always returns True

How can I make sure that any prospective plugin script **has not** implemented the `__init__` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hasattr` returns `True` for the presence of `__init__` because the minimal `class` we created inherits from `Object`, which comes with that method defined.

If we want to see what methods our minimal `class` has, *without getting the methods its `superclass` has defined*, you can call `__dict__` and get a `list` that's simple to test against using `.keys`:

```py
if '__init__' in minimal.__dict__.keys():
    raise RuntimeError("Plugins may not define __init__ methods")
```